# Why is XCode Compiling very slow after adding typescript?

Tags: xcode, typescript, react-native

I finally switched to typescript for my react native project this week.  I find it beautiful and awesome.  However, when I go to compile my project in Xcode, it is taking forever!(that is a metaphorical forever, approximately 30 minutes which is 6x longer than usual).

Am I missing something?  Is there a different typescript compile command?

I am running:

```
XCODE: Version 12.0.1 (12A7300)
deploying ios: 10 (in both the project and podfile)
RN: 0.63
typescript: 4.0.3
```

Comment: Build with timing summary and see where the time is spent

Comment: great idea.. I'll try that